# Compare keys of dictionary with list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of numbers (say, A). For example:

```
A = [ 0.1,  0.2,  0.3,  0.4,  0.5,  0.6,  0.7]
```

Many elements of the list A have lists associated with them and I store that result in the form of a dictionary. The keys of this dictionary are always elements which belong to the list A. For example,

```
D = {0.5: [1, 2], 0.7: [1, 1], 0.3: [7, 4, 4], 0.6: [5]}
```

In this example the elements **0.5**, **0.7**, **0.3** and **0.6** have lists attached with them and these elements serve as keys in the dictionary D.

For the elements of A that do not have lists attached with them (*viz* **0.1**, **0.2**, **0.3**), I want to attach them to the dictionary D (and assign empty lists to them) and create a new dictionary, D_new. For example,

```
D_new = {0.1: [], 0.2: [], 0.4: [], 0.5: [1, 2], 0.7: [1, 1], 
          0.3: [7, 4, 4], 0.6: [5]}
```

Comment: Using floating-point values as dict keys is usually a bad idea. Most floating-point operations are inherently imprecise, so you'll get surprises like a `KeyError` for `D_new[0.1+0.2]` because `0.1+0.2` isn't exactly `0.3`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a dict-comprehension, iterating over values in `A`, looking them up in `D` using `D.get()`, defaulting to `[]`.

```
D_new = { x: D.get(x, []) for x in A }
```

Comment: Brilliant! I love this solution

Answer (score 3):

You can also make a *defaultdict* from D:

```
from collections import defaultdict
D_new = defaultdict(list, D)

# the key in D returns corresponding value
D_new[0.5]
# [1, 2]

# the key not in D returns empty list
D_new[0.2]
# []
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use `dict.setdefault`:

```
D = {0.5: [1, 2], 0.7: [1, 1], 0.3: [7, 4, 4], 0.6: [5]}
A = [ 0.1,  0.2,  0.3,  0.4,  0.5,  0.6,  0.7]

for a in A:
    _ = D.setdefault(a, [])
    #                   ^ add's empty list as value if `key` not found
```

Final value:

```
>>> D
{0.5: [1, 2], 0.1: [], 0.2: [], 0.3: [7, 4, 4], 0.6: [5], 0.4: [], 0.7: [1, 1]}
```

*Note:* It is not creating the new `dict`, instead modifying the existing dict.